# What does the preprocessor do with "# <number> <filename>"?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I've just encountered a **C** file which contains both preprocessor directives and lines that look like this:

```
# 9 "filename"
```

I have never seen such lines before. What do they mean? I'm guessing these are preprocessor directives, but what does the preprocessor do with them?

Also, for some of the lines the string doesn't even represent an existing filename...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's another way of using the [#line](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc09lc.htm) preprocessor directive.

For example you could write:

```
// you could write #line 7 "filename"  or
// # 7 "filename"  or
// # 7  or
#line 7
int main(void)
{
      printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
```

And all of them would give you (in this case) `10` on `stdout`.

And a note about the "filename" part it's optional and unverified (that's why it can be anything, even a file that doesn't exist). Its use is explained in the link I provided - 
`If you specify a file name, the compiler views the next line as part of the specified file. If you do not specify a file name, the compiler views the next line as part of the current source file.`

Comment: Oh, so my question was misguided, and those *are* preprocessor directives after all.

Comment: @Oak - Yes, it's just another preprocessor directive. Good question through, it's harder to tell when they don't use the `line` portion of it.

Comment: Just checked and that is indeed the case :) thanks! Furthermore, it seems the string can be whatever string I want - even if it's not a legal filename - and it will just use it as file name (e.g. `__FILE__`).

Comment: It is a variant on the #line directive that is seen by the compiler proper, so it knows which line numbers to report syntax errors against, etc.  Logically, the compiler proper only sees preprocessed source, which doesn't even have line boundaries.  But it wouldn't be helpful if the compiler told you "problem at token 325,419"...